# Display result in the same page with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm basically starting my studies with PHP and what I’m trying to do is simple. I’d like to show the calculation result in the same page.

[This is the project’s structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGPVr.png)

Code!

index.php:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="calc.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <select name="cal" id="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="sub">Subtract</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

calc.php:

```
<?php

include 'includes/calc.inc.php';

$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$cal = $_POST['cal'];

$calculator = new Calc($num1, $num2, $cal);
echo $calculator->setCalc(); //gostaria de mostrar na mesma página
```

calc.inc.php:

```
<?php

class Calc{
    public $num1;
    public $num2;
    public $cal;

    public function __construct($num1, $num2, $cal){
        $this->num1 = $num1;
        $this->num2 = $num2;
        $this->cal = $cal;
    }

    public function setCalc(){
        switch($this->cal){
            case 'add':
                $result = $this->num1 + $this->num2;
                break;
            case 'sub':
                $result = $this->num1 - $this->num2;
                break;
            case 'mul':
                $result = $this->num1 * $this->num2;
                break;
            default:
                $result = "Error";
                break;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I get the values in the *index.php* page with the file *calc.php.* And the file *calc.php* I pass the values to *calc.inc.php* and that one makes the calculations and returns the final value to the *calc.php.* The trouble is the **method**. It’s redirectioned to *calc.php* page and the result is displayed in that page, **and I'd like it to appear on the same page as index.php.**

I Tried something with *Header(“Location: index.php”)* but this refreshes the page, so didn't work to me. Is that possible what I want? I accept differents solutions

Comment: You need to add the content of the file `clac.php` inside the `index.php` or include the `calc.php` in the `index.php` and change the form action to the `index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that might be overkill for this project, but will help you a lot with things like this in the future: [**Ajax**: Asynchronous JavaScript and XML](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp). Ajax is what lets you submit a form, process the form, and retrieve the results, without having to refresh or reload the page you're on. The easiest way to use Ajax is with the JavaScript framework [**jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You will need to include this line in your `<head>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

This line loads the jQuery framework, so instead of writing traditional JavaScript the hard way, you can use this speedy, efficient, and reliable markup language to dynamically modify your pages. Change your `<button type="submit">Calculate</button>` to **`<button class="mybutton">Calculate</button>`**, so we can select it with jQuery. Make sure to remove the `action="calc.php"` from your `<form>`, to keep it from submitting the traditional way.

Add this, somewhere in your page. It can be inside the `<form>` or outside it.

```
<div class="myresult"></div>
```

This is where the output from `calc.php` will appear. Now, add this in your `<head>`, make sure you add it after the `<script>` that includes the jQuery framework.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mybutton").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "calc.php",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $(".myresult").html(result);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

The code above will submit your form to **`calc.php`**, in the background. It will submit everything that's selected, and everything will be sent just like it always is. `calc.php` will process this **$_POST** data, and echo the result like you expect it to. The result will appear in the new div you created. I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is very good! I really want to start using PHP with JQuery(actually with AngularJS) and we're almost there @Tanner Babock !!! What is happening is the page is reloadind after I click to calculate! Can you help me? What that could be? And the result... Where is this passed through the PHP to JQuery? Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you. Try putting the `<button>` outside of the `<form>`, below it, just on its own. I think the way the <button> works is it submits the entire form that it's inside of. The `success: function(result) { ... }` is where the output from your PHP goes. Whatever your **`calc.php`** echoes, as output, is sent to the "result" parameter of the `success` function. You can safely assume that the **$_POST** data is being sent like always.

Comment: Also make sure your `<button>` does ***not*** have the `type="submit"` attribute, and make sure the `<form>` does not have the `action="calc.php"` attribute. These are the only things I can think of that would force the page to reload. If my answer works for you, please click the checkmark to the left of it to mark it as "accepted" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the form action Blank

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">
    <select name="cal" id="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="sub">Subtract</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

And include all the calculations you want to apply on same page , and to avoid errors use the function isset($_POST['num1']) for all your $post indexes .