# Can't display form results on same page with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to show the results of the submit button on the same page. I tried with several codes from here (specially this: [Display result in the same page with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783659/display-result-in-the-same-page-with-php)) but it didn't work.

This is how my html page looks like now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mybutton").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "https://catadordealfajores.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/calc.php",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $(".myresult").html(result);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  
  <input type="radio" name="causa" value="si">
  <label for="male">Sí</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="causa" value="No">
  <label for="female">No</label><br>
  
  <h3>¿Cuántos años trabajaste?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="anios">
  <br>  
</form>

<button class="mybutton">Calculate</button>
<div class="myresult"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Before Ajax, I had:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Calculadora de indemnización</h1>

<form action = "https://catadordealfajores.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/calc.php" method = "post">
  <h3>¿Te despidieron con causa?</h3>
  <p>Si trabajaste más de 3 meses, se considera 1 año. Si trabajaste 1 año y 3 meses, se consideran 2 años. Y así.</p> 
  <input type="radio" name="causa" value="si">
  <label for="male">Sí</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="causa" value="No">
  <label for="female">No</label><br>
  
  <h3>¿Cuántos años trabajaste?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="anios">
  <br>  

  <h3>¿Cuál era tu sueldo?</h3>
  <input type="text" name="sueldo">
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value = "Enviar">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Website: http://abogadoslaboralessanmartin.com.ar/7122-2/

Thank you very much

Comment: In your code, you sent it to another page. You can't show it on the same page if it anyways moves you to a different page. Please clarify your question.

Comment: what does `calc.php` have in it ? In your provided website link its redirecting to other page ?

Comment: Your current code works as it is, except the data property expects a live object, don't serialize it, jQuery does it for you. If fixing the data property won't make the code to work, you've to check the Network tab in the DevTools, see what is send with the request, and what is actually responded. If there's something wrong in these, you most likely have a problem on the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be?

"return false;" so that it doesn't go to another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('submit', 'form', function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "https://catadordealfajores.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/calc.php",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $(".myresult").html(result);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```